# Applying Different Header and Margins to the First Page (not title page) of a Multi-page LaTeX Document

Tags: header-footer, margins

How can I set up a LaTeX document where the first page has a specific header and unique margins, different from those on the second page, without manually specifying where the second page begins?

I'm working on a two-page cover letter. The first page should have a header (thus different margins), while the second page should have standard margins without a header. The length of the content on the first page is variable, so I need an automatic transition to the second page's layout.

Below is my current LaTeX code. As I am new to LaTeX, any improvements or suggestions are welcome.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{comment}

% Define the initial geometry for the first page
\geometry{
  top=2in, % Adjusted top margin for the first page
  headheight=1.1in, % Height of the header
  headsep=0.5in, % Separation between header and text
  bottom=1.2in,
  left=1.2in,
  right=1.2in,
  footskip=4.35004pt % Adjusted footskip to avoid a warning from fancyhdr
}

% Header settings for the first page
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  %%% Some logo will be here
  %% \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[height=1in]{some-logo.png}}
  \fancyhead[R]{My department\\My university\\Address line 1\\Address line 2}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % removes the horizontal line in the header
}

% Define a plain page style for other pages
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % optional: removes the horizontal line in the header
}

% Patch the \end{letter} command to change page style and geometry
\AtEndEnvironment{letter}{
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \newgeometry{
    top=1.2in, bottom=1.2in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in
  }
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{firstpage} % Apply the first page header style

\vspace{0.5in}

% Opening block
\today\\

\vspace{-0.1in}
Recipient's name,\\
Recipient's Institution,\\
Recipient's address line 1,\\
Recipient's address line 2\\

Dear\ Dr. Jon Doe,

% Body
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\noindent{}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ultrices aliquet. Cras ac placerat ex, non rhoncus tortor. Phasellus accumsan sit amet felis vitae varius. Nullam efficitur lorem nec orci scelerisque, commodo rutrum arcu varius. Nullam orci metus, rutrum sit amet enim sit amet, luctus rutrum metus. Vivamus commodo, quam a euismod venenatis, felis lorem porta massa, ac cursus massa nibh eu lectus. Duis pretium in elit nec sodales. Vivamus consectetur tristique ante eget ultricies. Cras sed lectus luctus, commodo urna fringilla, placerat urna.

\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.

\noindent{}Fusce mauris enim, maximus in lorem mattis, volutpat euismod nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse ac leo cursus, bibendum justo eget, laoreet risus. In sodales nisl vel viverra fringilla. Ut venenatis nisl id dapibus mollis. In elit tellus, venenatis sit amet lacinia in, cursus id erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque pharetra risus eu ex luctus bibendum. Proin dictum neque sit amet mauris viverra, et hendrerit lacus elementum. 

\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.

%% My problem: Is there any way to make this at the start of the second page AUTOMATICALLY (i.e. after how many paragraphs)?
  \pagestyle{plain}
  \newgeometry{
    top=1.2in, bottom=1.2in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in
  }

\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.

% Closer
\vspace{0.2in}

\begin{flushleft}
Thank you for your consideration,

\vspace{0.2in}
Jack Doe\\
\vspace{0.2in}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One solution is to use flowfram on the first page.  Personally, I would just overlap the header with tikzpagenodes and add an extra 0.8in gap at the top of the first text area.

Comment: you don't need to change the margins which in general is not possible at an automatic page break, just use a suitable space at the top of the first page

Comment: also remove all the `\\ ` that generate underfill badness 10000 warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `\AddToHookNext{shipoout/background}` to overlay the header on the first page.   The `\put` coordinates are relative to the upper left corner of the page.  I located the lower right corner of the header, used `\llap` to move it left and a tabular [b] to handle multiple lines and move it up.

BTW, it is not a good idea to include every package you have ever used in every document.  I strive to never load a package if it is not needed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{comment}

% Define the initial geometry for the first page
\geometry{ top=1.2in, bottom=1.2in, left=1.2in, right=1.2in}% showframe
\pagestyle{empty}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put ({\dimexpr\paperwidth-1.2in},-1.5in)% lower right corner
  {\llap{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}% or r
    My department\\My university\\Address line 1\\Address line 2
  \end{tabular}}}}
  
\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.5in}

% Opening block
\today

\vspace{-0.1in}
Recipient's name,\\
Recipient's Institution,\\
Recipient's address line 1,\\
Recipient's address line 2\\

Dear\ Dr. Jon Doe,

% Body
\setlength\parindent{24pt}

\noindent{}Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc aliquam ultrices aliquet. Cras ac placerat ex, non rhoncus tortor. Phasellus accumsan sit amet felis vitae varius. Nullam efficitur lorem nec orci scelerisque, commodo rutrum arcu varius. Nullam orci metus, rutrum sit amet enim sit amet, luctus rutrum metus. Vivamus commodo, quam a euismod venenatis, felis lorem porta massa, ac cursus massa nibh eu lectus. Duis pretium in elit nec sodales. Vivamus consectetur tristique ante eget ultricies. Cras sed lectus luctus, commodo urna fringilla, placerat urna.

\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.

\noindent{}Fusce mauris enim, maximus in lorem mattis, volutpat euismod nibh. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse ac leo cursus, bibendum justo eget, laoreet risus. In sodales nisl vel viverra fringilla. Ut venenatis nisl id dapibus mollis. In elit tellus, venenatis sit amet lacinia in, cursus id erat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque pharetra risus eu ex luctus bibendum. Proin dictum neque sit amet mauris viverra, et hendrerit lacus elementum. 

\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.


\noindent{}Aliquam ut ligula orci. Sed cursus interdum ante, et cursus erat aliquam vel. Maecenas sodales ligula mattis condimentum convallis. Donec aliquet ut libero eget dignissim. Etiam gravida bibendum venenatis. Maecenas accumsan magna lectus. Mauris leo urna, tincidunt at eros vel, consequat varius urna. Curabitur blandit, nunc sed ultricies vehicula, neque turpis blandit massa, pulvinar ultrices orci ligula et enim. Morbi at efficitur ipsum. Aliquam ullamcorper consequat nunc, quis pulvinar orci facilisis sit amet. Pellentesque volutpat quam vitae luctus euismod.

% Closer
\vspace{0.2in}

\begin{flushleft}% as in \parskip=0pt ?
Thank you for your consideration,

\vspace{0.2in}
Jack Doe\\
\vspace{0.2in}

\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```